# c Open() function

Tags: c, file, file-permissions

I have some trouble understanding the arguments in the open function, specifically used in the context of creating an output file. I do not quite understand the roles of flags and file permissions (the 2nd and 3rd arguments in the function). For instance, if I have the file permission 00200 (user has write permission), and the flag O_RDONLY (Read only), then can I read the file or write the file?

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `open` is as follows:

```
 int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

There are three sets of "permissions" at play: The permissions of the file itself, the flags, and the mode.

The permissions of the file itself (e.g. 00200 meaning only user can write) specify what the operating system *allows* a program to do.

When you specify the flags, you indicate what you *want* to do with the file. For example, if the file is readonly to you (e.g. `rwxr-xr-x` and you're not the owner), you will be allowed to open the file with `O_RDONLY`. If you attempt to open the file with `O_RDWR` or `O_WRONLY`, you will receive an `EPERM` (operation not permitted) error in `errno`.

The `mode` parameter is only relevant when you create a *new* file, such as when you open a file that doesn't exist<sup>1</sup> and the flag `O_CREAT` is specified. The file is created on the filesystem and its permissions are given by `mode & ~umask` (see [`man 2 umask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) for more details).

<sup>1</sup> Of course, the containing directory must exist and you must have write+exec permissions on that directory.